# HTTPS SSL certificate does not work on NGINX

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, nginx

I have two docker containers running on AWS elastic beanstalk. One container has my web application(django) and the other has my NGINX server. I have a positiveSSL certificate verified for my domain name, after configuring my NGINX to accept HTTPS and it seems like the website refuses to connect over HTTPS and only works on HTTP

I have my AWS security groups open to accept traffic from port 443 and my certificate is valid so I can only assume I am not setting my nginx correctly

```
upstream app {

    server app:8000;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
    ssl_certificate /app/ssl/mysite_chain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /app/ssl/mysite.key;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }

    location /staticfiles/ {
        alias /app/staticfiles/;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {

        proxy_pass http://app;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;

    }

    location /staticfiles/ {
        alias /app/staticfiles/;
    }
}
```

Everything is working fine when I use normal HTTP and I don't get any logs from NGINX on HTTPS for some reason. The only message I get is from my browser saying the 'site can't be reached' and that the 'website refused the connection'. Is there something obvious here I am missing?

Comment: Is it single instance setup, no load balancer?

Comment: Yes it is a single EC-2 Instance running on elastic beanstalk. I am starting to think of just using an SSL on an elastic load balancer with one instance because the network inside amazon is secure so it might be not worth the time to secure the server directly